# Understanding self in Python pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, self

Hello I'm a beginner Python programmer working on a platform pygame game and whilst looking through some code from http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/en/sprite_sheets/ there was a particular section on the player class which I do not understand.

From the player class there's a section of the code on line 102

```
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
```

Since platform_list is not declared in this class, how is it possible that it is used in this way? Also, how is it possible to do level.platform_list? I've tried the code from the website mentioned above and it works perfectly but I do not understand how this works. Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zondo says, the `Player` class defines the `level` attribute and initializes it to `None`.

The missing step in his answer is that `main()` in `platform_scroller.py` fills this in with the cuurent level at line 57.  Since this is a `Level` class, it has a `platform_list` attribute and can be accessed through `self.level.platform_list` inside the `Player` object.

Answer (score 0):

On line 13 the `Player` class is defined.  In its `__init__` method, on line 39, its `level` attribute is initialized to `None`.  Presumable that attribute is later changed, because it is used on line 104 to get its `platform_list` attribute: `block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)`

Comment: But how about the platform_list? The only place it is initialised is in the Level class. How does that fit into the picture?

Comment: That's what I meant.  Presumable it is changed somewhere else in the program.

Answer (score -1):

It is initialized to None around line 37-38 in the Player class.

```
# List of sprites we can bump against
self.level = None
```

Comment: I've seen that but how does that connect to the platform_list which is only initialized in the Level class?